# Is there a way to distinguish Cantonese and Mandarin when creating a mp4 file by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles

I have a `video.mp4` that doesn't have audio and two audio file `th.m4a`(Thai) and `ch.m4a`(Chinese[Cantonese]).

And I want to merge these files to a single mp4 file by `ffmpeg` like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -i th.m4a -i ch.m4a -map 0:0 -metadata:s:v:0:0 language=chi -map 1:0 -metadata:s:a:0:0 language=tha -map 2:0 -metadata:s:a:1:0 language=chi -c copy out.mp4
```

It works fine, but I want to set the audio language Cantonese(direct of Chinese).
I couldn't find 3 characters for the Cantonese.

I tried with `title` option,

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -i th.m4a -i ch.m4a -map 0:0 -metadata:s:v:0:0 language=chi -map 1:0 -metadata:s:a:0:0 language=tha -map 2:0 -metadata:s:a:1:0 language=chi title="Cantonese" -c copy out.mp4
```

but it failed with a error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'title=Cantonese'
```

Is there a way to embed the info that distinguish Cantonese and Mandarin?

Comment: In `-metadata:s:a:1:0 language=chi title="Cantonese"`, there should be no `language=chi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata option has to be used for each individual key that has to be set. So, in `-metadata:s:a:1:0 language=chi title="Cantonese"`, `title="Cantonese"` is interpreted as the output filename. The correct syntax is `-metadata:s:a:1:0 title="Cantonese"`